# Django migration being killed

Tags: python, django, postgresql, migration

I'm quite confident with Django, but have mostly relied on generated migrations until recently. I wrote a small custom migration, and shortly after my CI started complaining about timeouts and it ends up that it had something to do with the migrations from Django during deploy.

At first, I was able to fix this issue, but I don't know what I did (if anything) that repaired it. The issue seems to be related to some custom code I was entering for a specific migration. Here's what I know:

- Initially, all was fine, but the migrations started taking a *really* long time to run (relatively) after adding my custom code. About 10 seconds at time.
- It works sometimes. ie. If I run the migration ten times from the command line, sometimes it will work and sometimes it will fail.

The output is as follows (app names edited out):

```
[web@dev myapp]$ ./manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: myapp1, myapp2, myapp3, myapp4
Running migrations:
Killed
```

- At first I thought it was because I am using `RunPython` to run a Python function that copies data between two fields before deleting one of the fields. The documentation discourages its use for PostgreSQL, but is there a better way to do this?
- The business scenario here is that I had a boolean field that I needed to switch to a set of options (CharField with `options`). The code checks if the boolean was true and sets the correct value for the character field. I have done this twice. The first time ended up working eventually, but I haven't tested it on another database yet.

This is the migration (app names edited out):

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations

def fix_consulting(apps, schema_editor):
    my_model = apps.get_model("myapp", "MyModel")
    for m in my_model._default_manager.all():
        if m.consulting:
            m.detail = "CONSLT"
            m.save()


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('myapp', '0024_auto_20160117_1113'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(fix_consulting,atomic=False),
    ]
```

My thoughts:

- Maybe the code I'm writing here is taking too long to run? There are less than one hundred models in the database so I don't know why the `fix_consulting` function would take so long.
- If I add print statements at the beginning of `fix_consulting`, they only run sometimes, and are killed other times. As it stands, I've ran it 6-8 times and it has been killed every time, but at different points

Other information:
- Using Django 1.9
- Using PostgreSQL 9.4.4
- Error occurs mostly on CentOS, but also OSX

Comment: Its possible that your machine just isn't able to store the data retrieved by `all`, so its possible that changing your entire loop to `my_model._default_manager.filter(consulting=True).update(detail="CONSLT")` might fix the issue... I'd be happy to make this an answer if im correct

Comment: I'll give this a shot! It is a server with a fairly small amount of memory.

Comment: You're correct! The error was two-fold. Once I changed it to the code you provided, it exposed another error that was resolved quite easily because it actually gave me a stack trace. Thank you! Go ahead and add the answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe your issue was caused by the amount of data that you may need to cache when using `all` since this returns all instances of an object, therefore you can do the filtering on a database level before returning the objects, since you then only need to change values of a field you may as well do that on a database level too. Altogether this will change your code to the following.

```
def fix_consulting(apps, schema_editor):
    my_model = apps.get_model("myapp", "MyModel")
    my_model._default_manager.filter(consulting=True).update(detail="CONSLT")
```

This puts the memory management responsibilities on the database which appears to have solved your issue.

Going forward, I'd recommend trying to always filter down what is returned from a db to only that that is actually needed (be that by splicing or filtering)

Answer (score 0):

If any of your model's fields are large in size then maybe the problem is the Memory getting used up. If this field is not necessary for the migration computation, just leave it out using `defer()` or `only()`.

E.g. to **only load necessary fields** *location* and *category* you could do something like:

```
for item in Item.objects.only('location', 'category').all()
    Item.objects.filter(pk=item.pk).update(location=category.default_location)
```

Background:

I was facing a similar issue on Google compute VMs - My Django migration was getting killed when running on a large database. I discovered that it was not only the CPU usage spiking but also the Memory and the memory-swapping causing a lot of swap disk I/O.

I tried Sayse's solution (switching from save() to update()) and although it did help speed things up on my (smaller) test database, the migration was still failing on the main production database.

Ultimately, I realized that the memory was getting used up because of one particular json field in my model which was quite large. This field was unnecessary for processing the migration, so I simply tightened up which fields were being loaded from the database by using `only()`.